# Show different images based on property value

Tags: wix, burn

I would like to do the following:

```
<Image X="0" Y="0" Width="20" Height="20" ImageFile="[Status].bmp" />
```

where `Status` is a variable. Currently this does not work, since contents of `ImageFile` attribute don't seem to be expanded.

I implemented a custom `bafunctions.dll`, but couldn't find how to get to controls via `IBootstrapperEngine`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WiX v4, you would do it like this:

```
<ImageControl X="0" Y="0" Width="20" Height="20" ImageFile="Status1.bmp"
              VisibleCondition="Status = Status1" />
<ImageControl X="0" Y="0" Width="20" Height="20" ImageFile="Status2.bmp"
              VisibleCondition="Status = Status2" />
```

Although, the page would not refresh automatically.  You might have to use

```
ThemeShowPageEx(pTheme, pTheme->dwCurrentPageId, SW_SHOW, THEME_SHOW_PAGE_REASON_REFRESH);
```

In WiX v3, there's no supported way to do this.  The bafunctions.dll would need access to the `THEME` but WixStdBA doesn't provide that in v3.  I guess you could theoretically get the top level window and enumerate all the child controls until you find the right control to show or hide, and set them initially to not visible.

```
 <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="20" Height="20" ImageFile="Status1.bmp" Visible="no />
 <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="20" Height="20" ImageFile="Status2.bmp" Visible="no />
```